# What is the difference between VirtualAlloc and VirtualProtect?

Tags: winapi

[`VirtualProtect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotect)  changes the protection on a region of committed pages in the virtual address space of the calling process.

[`VirtualAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) reserves, commits, or changes the state of a region of pages in the virtual address space of the calling process. Memory allocated by this function is automatically initialized to zero.

As I understand, `VirtualAlloc` can also change the protection on a region, so why is `VirtualProtect` needed?

**EDIT:**
I would think I am changing the protection of the region in the following? (x32dbg)

```
VirtualAlloc(address, mbi.RegionSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ);
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

I thought I just changed protection here through VirtualAlloc?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: yes, agree. `VirtualAlloc` can change protection of region, despite this and undocumented

Comment: Is it bad practise to do so, then? I am a bit confused :D

Comment: what sense use `VirtualAlloc` for change protect when exist `VirtualProtect` ? unclear are this not changed for `VirtualAlloc`, `VirtualProtect` return old protection.. not view any sense use `VirtualAlloc` for change protect even if this is possible

Comment: One example is to `VirtualAlloc()` a block of virtual memory for read/write access initially, populate it with executable instructions, and then `VirtualProtect()` it afterwards to remove write access and give it execution access. This is a common solution for creating dynamic callbacks/thunks at runtime.

Comment: @jubibanna One of difference based on the document of `VirtualAlloc` is *"If lpAddress specifies an address within an enclave, flProtect cannot be any of the following values: PAGE_NOACCESS, PAGE_GUARD, PAGE_NOCACHE and PAGE_WRITECOMBINE."* But there is no such limitation for `VirtualProtect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualAlloc() allocates new memory

VirtualProtect() changes the page permissions of memory that already is allocated